# django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"

Tags: python, django, postgresql

My settings are local all @authmethodlocal@.

It's like I can't get into my user "postgres" or "ladonna".

I was running python3 manage.py runserver.

local host, 5432, etc are default.

```
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py", line 126, in connect
    conn = _connect(dsn, connection_factory=connection_factory, **kwasync)
django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

Comment: As the error says you are not providing the password or the password that you have provided is incorrect

Comment: "@authmethodlocal@" is part of the template file used by initdb to construct the real pg_hba.conf.  If that were in your real pg_hba.conf, that database would refuse to start.

Answer (score 2):

The user postgres has no DB password by default. So, Check the file /etc/postgresql/10/main/pg_hba.conf: And change it to

```
local   all         postgres                          peer
```

Or Inside the psql shell you can set the password for user postgres

```
ALTER USER postgres PASSWORD 'yourPassword';
```

After setting password, add password in django settings for user postgres.

Comment: I did `local   all         postgres                          peer` and in order to access `psql shell` I did `docker-compose run --rm main_postgres_service_name psql -h main_postgres_service_name -U postgres_user -d postgres_database` then it wants password  so when I put password it gives `django.db.utils.OperationalError: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"`

Answer (score 0):

This error is not due to Django, this error is coming from PostgreSQL and it is saying that the connection to the server is failing because password authentication failed. Check the password of the user you are entering in Django settings.py.

If this doesn't work sometimes you have to make some changes in the pg_hba.conf file. Visit [xTuple Admin Guide - Edit your pg_hba.conf file](https://manuals.xtuple.com/prodguide/admin-guide/ch01s12s01s01.html).

If this doesn't work, you can check your port on which this is working by using command

```
sudo netstat -plunt |grep postgres
```

and change the port in your settings.py.